# scipy's solve_ivp has a keyword events. My question is regarding this keyword

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

As I understand the solve_ivp documentation, the function event(t, y, arg) required by events=event must be such, that
$event(t_0, y_0, args) = 0. if the event has happened.
solve_ivp then tries to improve the time and coordinates of the event.
I do not have such a continuous function, during integration, I 'look' numerically whether the event has taken place, and I believe (I have no proof) that this optimization makes my solutions more critical.

My question: Is there any way to 'tell' solve_ivp not to attempt this optimization, but just accept the event has happened and terminate the integration?
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "critical"?

Comment: What I meant is this: I only have a numerical criterium to see whether the event has taken place. When there is an event, (I guess) solve_ivp moves back and forth, but my numerical function does not necessarily mone between plus and minus around the event. In any case, solve_inp misses events. Ideally, what I am looking for is a key word, say break, so anytime I set break=True during the integration solve_ivp stops and returns the results achieved so far. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you have a function that normally returns negative one but then returns positive one when your numerical criteria is reached?

Comment: Do you mean, my numerical function should return -1 while the event is not true, and should return +1 when it is true? YES, I can do this, but I thought my numerical function should return 0 when the event is true.  Thanks again!

Comment: I did it exactly like you said: my numerical function returns -1 when the criterium is not met, and it returns +1 if it is met. Now all works perfect! Thanks a LOT for your help!!!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Updated my answer to show this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to 'tell' solve_ivp not to attempt this optimization, but just accept the event has happened and terminate the integration? Thanks for any help!!

This is already what `solve_ivp` does for the most part.  It looks for a sign change of the function over one step (see `events` documentation below).  It then uses the interpolation functions of the integrator solution to estimate the time at which it occurred.  See link to code portion that does the root finding.  Note that it doesn't use the ODE or the event function, but the interpolation functions from the solution.

Since `solve_ivp` only looks for a sign change, you can set your event function to change sign when your condition is met.  It won't recalculate the event function inside when estimating the exact event time.  For example,

```py
def event(t, y):
    if <condition you are looking for>:
        return 1
    return -1
```

### References

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

> events: callable, or list of callables, optional
>
> > Events to track. If None (default), no events will be tracked. Each event occurs at the zeros of a continuous function of time and state. Each function must have the signature event(t, y) and return a float. The solver will find an accurate value of t at which event(t, y(t)) = 0 using a root-finding algorithm. By default, all zeros will be found. The solver looks for a sign change over each step, so if multiple zero crossings occur within one step, events may be missed. Additionally each event function might have the following attributes:  [redacted more details]

Portion of code that finds the event time: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f68525ef0270d7b0b1206e11b264b792c9ee6e6f/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py#L53-L78

Comment: Thanks for helping! My criterium is not a continuous function of time and state, but some numerical criterium only. It may not switch from minus to plus around the critical point.  In any case, solve_ivp finds some events, and misses other events. Thanks again!!  What I would like to have is a key word, call it break, so every time break=True during integration, solve_ivp stops and returns the results obtained so far. :-)

Comment: The answer was updated to be more explicit on discreteness of an event.